# edx video doenloader issue with edx-dl a github project

Tags: python, github

I want to download all edx course's lecture using `**edx-dl**`. I already install the latest version of python on my system Windows-7 (32-bit).

I use python `edx-dl.py -u raktimbanerjee9@gmail.com --list-courses` to discover the courses which I already enrolled.

github link: https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl

But it makes some problem. I stuck for that...
[look the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3DH.jpg)I cannot understand what happened. Please solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you install it? Did you do the `pip install edx-dl` or did you simply download the files from github?

Comment: No, I do not use `pip install edx-dl`. I download if open command prompt on the folder and run  `edx-dl.py -u raktimbanerjee9@gmail.com --list-courses`. Actually [I followed this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvAS835JiTI)

Comment: I try to install it using `pip install edx-dl`. But command prompt show pip is not recognazid as an internal or external command...But how to fix this. I already install latest version of python on the system and also update the Environment Variable. Then Why?

Comment: Add pip to your PATH? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709194/278545

Comment: Yes, I do everything and now it works well.

Comment: @Rakim It would be worth describing what exactly you did step by step in an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's right .